# How can i add cache control code to htaccess?

Tags: php, joomla2.5

How can I add cache control code to .htaccess?

My site is slow and I found 35 static components without a far-future expiration date.

How can I add expiration data for that? I was informed that this could be done in the .htaccess file but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
# Cache Files
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</filesMatch>
```

This caches any file ending with ico|pdf|flv|jpg..... for 604800 seconds, which is one week, you can change that number to cache for however long you feel you need.