# Leverage browser caching for some css and javascript file only

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache

Is there any way to browser caching for some css and javascript files only through htaccess file?
I have three css files

```
http://www.example.com/css/main.css 
http://www.example.com/css/star_rating.css 
http://www.example.com/js/jquery.autocomplete.css
```

"main.css" may be chaged day by day. I want caching for star_rating.css and jquery.autocomplete.css only, not for main.css. How can I achieve this?

Also is there any way to caching google adsense javascript file.

```
https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.1/runtime.js 
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js 
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js
```

Comment: You can consider adding `get` data to the request for `main.css` and cache it anyway. Something like `...css/main.css?v=01` This way you can control when to force the request for the new file by changing the `v` number.

Comment: @wiktus239: Some browsers are known to disable caching when there's a query parameter in the url (probably to work-around bugs when devs set bad caching rules that affect ajax data). The best solution is to put the version number in the url itself: `...css/01/main.css` and user rewrite rules to point it to the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Set a cache-control header in your HTTP Response, in .htaccess, already answered here:  [How can i add cache control code to htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669513/how-can-i-add-cache-control-code-to-htaccess)

You will need a subsequent  rule to reduce the cache interval of main.css, to whatever you need.  However, before you go ahead with that...

Personally, I wouldn't bother with such sophisticated granularity, just set your cache time so the resources are only requested once for a typical browsing session (24 hours?).  Although some browser caches can be rather large, there's no guarantee a busy user is going to still have your resources cached the next time they visit your site, if they fill their cache, the less frequent/stale items will be removed.

For long-term caching strategies I would just check that ETag support is working on your servers.  If a browser already has one of your items cached, it will request with an "If Not Modified" header and provide the ETag it holds for your resource.

If the resource has not been modified (if the ETag values match), your server will respond with a 304 (Not Modified) instead of a 200, a good saving for large resources.

You cannot influence the response headers if hot-linking to the Google AdSense JavaScript files and not hosting them yourself, but they should have sensible cache-control headers (set by Google) anyway I would expect.